# subset sum through DP

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a concise explanation on this approach at http://comproguide.blogspot.in/2013/10/subset-sum-problem.html
However,I enumerate this algorithm through a small exercise to find sub-sets in  {1,2,3,4} that sum to 4.

I notice that the cells {1,1},{2,2} return a false.

Did I understand the logic wrong?
Or does the algorithm does not consider the set to be a subset of itself?

I would have expected {1,1} to return a true as 1 adds upto itself.

Comment: I don't think it uses the same value twice. Althought i wonder why you think {1,1} will return true as the sum of that isn't 4 and {2,2} wont because it only can use the 2 once.

Comment: matrix[i][j] = true; indicates that there is a subset of array[0..j-1] which contains the sum i.....This means {1,1} indicates subsets which sum up to 1 - or is it not so?

Comment: the sum is not i. In the example it looks for subsets of sum = 100 and then sum = 200. The matrix example only returns true or false because it uses a boolean expression , in this case for 100 its false and for 200 its true. subsets can contain more then 2 values that add up to 200 {37, 62, 101} for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{1} should count as a subset that sums to 1. I've added some output to the program to show the table:

```
public class SubsetSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        hasSum(array, 4);
    }

    public static boolean hasSum(int [] array, int sum) {
        int len = array.length;
        boolean[][] table = new boolean[sum+1][len+1];
        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++) table[0][i] = true;
        for(int i = 1; i <= sum; i++) table[i][0] = false;
        for(int i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= len; j++) {
                table[i][j] = table[i][j-1];
                if(!table[i][j] && i >= array[j-1]) {
                    table[i][j] = table[i-array[j-1]][j-1];
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%10s ", "-");
        for(int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s ", i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s ", j);
            for(int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%10s ", table[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return table[sum][len];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
     -          0          1          2          3          4 
     0       true      false      false      false      false 
     1       true       true      false      false      false 
     2       true       true       true       true      false 
     3       true       true       true       true       true 
     4       true       true       true       true       true
```

These results look correct. I would interpret some of the values like:

- table[0][0] is true because {} sums to 0
- table[1][1] is true because {1} sums to 1
- table[2][2] is true because {2} sums to 2
- table[3][2] is true because {1,2} sums to 3
- table[4][3] is true because {1,3} sums to 4

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the post. What ever output shown by @fgb looks correct. I don't see any problem with the code. Is there anything wrong with my explanation?